# How to do 20% order size for each transaction, not total of 20%

Tags: pine-script

I have tradingview set to do 20% of initial capital amount for each order but I want each order to be 20% of the amount until the 100% is used up not just 20% total. I am not sure how to do this. Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Step1) Here's how to define the strategy section:

```
strategy(title, shorttitle, overlay, initial_capital= [put full amount here], ....etc)
```

step2) when you call for an order

```
strategy.entry(id, long, qty=[floor(strategy.initial_capital*0.2/close)], ...etc)
```